# ffprobe/ffmpeg subtitle index mismatch

Tags: ffmpeg, video

So this is driving me insane.

I have a video file, `input.mkv`, with several subtitle streams. I want to hardcode one of these subtitle streams into a new file. I usually do this like so:

```
inputfile="input.mkv"
outputfile="out.mp4"
ffmpeg -i "$inputfile" -vf "subtitles=$(printf "%q" "$inputfile")" "$outputfile"
```

Now since `input.mkv` has multiple sub streams, I need to specify which one I want. Enter `ffprobe`:

(I'll cut some irrelevant (I think) fields for readability)

```
$ ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams -select_streams s input.mkv | jq -r '.streams | .[]'
{
  "index": 2,
...cut...
  },
  "tags": {
    "language": "zh-Hans",
    "title": "中文（简体）",
    "DURATION": "00:23:40.083000000"
  }
}
{
  "index": 3,
...cut...
  },
  "tags": {
    "language": "zh-Hant",
    "title": "中文（繁體）| 繁化姬",
    "DURATION": "00:23:40.083000000"
  }
}
{
  "index": 4,
...cut...
  },
  "tags": {
    "language": "en",
    "title": "English",
    "DURATION": "00:23:40.083000000"
  }
}
{
  "index": 5,
...cut...
  },
  "tags": {
    "language": "th",
    "title": "ภาษาไทย",
    "DURATION": "00:23:40.079000000"
  }
}
{
  "index": 6,
...cut...
  },
  "tags": {
    "language": "vi",
    "title": "Tiếng Việt",
    "DURATION": "00:23:40.039000000"
  }
}
{
  "index": 7,
...cut...
  },
  "tags": {
    "language": "id",
    "title": "Bahasa Indonesia",
    "DURATION": "00:23:40.079000000"
  }
}
{
  "index": 8,
...cut...
  },
  "tags": {
    "language": "ms",
    "title": "Bahasa Melayu",
    "DURATION": "00:23:40.080000000"
  }
}
```

Now I want the english sub stream, so I'd think I need sub stream 4:

```
$ ffmpeg -i "$inputfile" -to 00:00:10 -vf "subtitles=$(printf "%q" "$inputfile"):si=4" out.mp4
```

However, this gets me a sub language I cannot read (or identify).
After trying different indices, index 2 got me the english stream:

```
$ ffmpeg -i "$inputfile" -to 00:00:10 -vf "subtitles=$(printf "%q" "$inputfile"):si=2" out.mp4
```

I would like to do all this in a script, and use the index from ffprobe to get the correct stream:

```
$ ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams -select_streams s "$inputfile" | jq -r '.streams | .[] | select(.tags.language=="en") | .index'
4
```

Why is it that they do not match up?
Is there a better way to get the correct index? Is it maybe always 2 less?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

//ffmpeg version info:

```
$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your english subtitle streams is:

- the 5th stream (hence index 4) of the file (absolute position)
- the 3rd subtitle stream (hence index 2) of the file (relative position)

Hence the ambiguity... the `subtitles` filter requires the relative position. It could be easier in two steps:

```
ffmpeg -i "$inputfile" -map 0:s:language:en -c copy sub.mkv
ffmpeg -i "$inputfile" -vf "subtitles=sub.mkv" "$outputfile"
```

The first ffmpeg will keep only the english subtitle stream and put it in `sub.mkv`. Then the second one doesn't has to care about the index.

Comment: ooh, that explains it all. 
I prefer not to use an intermediate file, so I've solved it now by getting the nr of sub streams and total nr of streams, and substracting the difference.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can accept the answer if it fits your question ;)

Comment: I did search for such an option, but I couldn't find it. Where is the accept button? :)

Comment: Citing the help page: "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in." https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers